# Knockout Click Binding Except When Dragging

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, jquery-ui-draggable

I have sliders on my site that allow the user to select via dragging, or clicking on an item.  When they drag, the item closest to the vertical center of the parent is chosen.

### [CodePen Demo](http://codepen.io/brigand/pen/aClsp)

The problem is that the Knockout click binding is being bound before the jQuery UI draggable option (implemented in a custom binding).

To reproduce, try clicking and dragging on the bottom number, and move it up a little (but not in the center).  Try doing that a few times, as it seems to work correctly on the first drag... sometimes.

The binding basically calls `.draggable`, and updates an observable when dragging stops.

The HTML is set up like this.

```
<ul data-bind="slideSelect: thing, foreach: nums">
  <li data-bind="click: $root.thing.set($data), text: $data">1</li>
</ul>
```

Is there any way to make the draggable element stop the `li`s click events from firing?  I'd like to do it in the cleanest fashion possible.

Comment: I cannot recreate the behavior you are describing. It works for me every time

Answer (score 0):

did you try event.preventDefault(); in on drag event handler? the idea is if you detect drag event then stop the event bubbling. if click  happens before drag then i think you might have to wait to see if drag happens then complete the action.

Comment: I think I'll end up binding the clicks in my custom binding.  I'll just have an option to turn it on/off.